# Crystal Reports number field becomes 100 times smaller with Norwegian regional settings

Tags: windows, localization, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

Our application has a crystal report (v.8) set to display a certain "Amount" field in Norwegian currency format (dots and commas switch places: 1,234.56 becomes 1.234,56). This field's value is fetched using a database connection by the report.
Now if the machine's regional settings are kept English(US), the report works as expected. But for Norwegian regional settings, the amounts become 100 times less. i.e. if amount for a record in the database is 1.234,56 (1,234.56 in en-US), on the report it turns out to be 12,34 (100 times less than original).
What could be the issue here? How can I get it working with Norwegian settings since those are the machine defaults?

Screenshot below shows how the field has been formatted in the crystal report. Another weird thing is that, instead of custom style, if I choose 'System Default Number Format' and click OK, this selection doesn't get saved, on viewing the formatting of the field again it will show 'Custom Style' selected. [Using crystal reports v8.5]

[image: Formatting for Amount field]

Details:

- Operating System: Windows Server 2003 R2
- Application platform: COM - Visual Basic 6.
- Crystal Reports version: 8/8.5
- Database: MS SQL Server 2008 (ODBC)

**Update:** On whether ODBC connection (vs. native) is the problem - If I use ODBC connection under Crystal Reports application, this report works correctly. Issue occurs only if I run it via our application.

Comment: Which database are you using?  Does this situation occur with other reporting tools (e.g. Access)?  Which driver are you using?  It is a native driver or ODBC?

Comment: If the problem is resolved when using Crystal Reports and ODBC (without the application stack), then your application stack is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we upgraded the app to Crystal Reports 10 developer components and the issue disappeared. Found no way of fixing this while it was still on CR8.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, try switching from an ODBC driver to a 'native' driver.  See if the problem is resolved.

Comment: If I use ODBC connection under Crystal Reports application, this report works correctly. Issue occurs only if I run it via our application. So I guess ODBC is not the culprit here. Any other ideas? The database is SQL Server 2008.